# Visual Studio 2019 Vertical Tabs Background Color

Tags: themes, visual-studio-2019

Anybody knows how to set the background for the vertical tabs?
I love that feature, but with my favourite theme you can't see squat...

[...its gray on gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzijY.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I wasn't able to find a way to change the background color, but at least I found a way to change the foreground color, so that at least the tabs become visible.
I have installed Color Theme Editor for VS 2019. It comes with many themes, which you can make a copy of, then edit the copy. In the color theme editor you must search for Document Well - Tab, then scroll to Unselected. Changing the background color here unfortunately only affects horizontal tabs, but changing the foreground do affects both horizontal and vertical tabs.
Here is a screenshot of the extension in action:

[image]

Don't forget to click on the "Save and apply theme" in the upper left corner of the extension page.